# Accurate voltage switching device

Tags: mosfet

I imagine the answer to this question is no, but I'll give it a shot anyway.

Are there any components that can switch (i.e. open and close a current path between two pins) accurately based on an input voltage, while not themselves consuming any current? Like a mosfet with an accurate threshold voltage and a narrower transition between not-conducting and conducting well.

Comment: Are you hoping to monitor the voltage across the switch (which will fall to zero when the switch is closed) or somewhere else. I think if you explain the real problem you will avoid us wasting a lot of time.

Comment: As it stands, the only answer to this question is no. Something somewhere needs to consume some current or power. Accurately is also meaningless...

Comment: @Transistor It's not really for a specific application, but one of the things I was thinking about was battery voltage monitoring, so turning on a switch when the voltage falls (or rises) above a certain voltage. The accuracy would probably need to be +-50mv on a voltage of 1V-5V, and the current would need to be max 1uA

Comment: @BeB00: The problem with battery monitoring is that the battery voltage will change when the switch is opened and closed due to the battery's internal resistance. You'll be making an oscillator.

Comment: @Transistor I'm assuming that it wouldn't be directly switching the power to the rest of the system

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any components that can switch (i.e. open and close a current path between two pins) accurately based on an input voltage, while not themselves consuming any current? Like a mosfet with an accurate threshold voltage and a narrower transition between not-conducting and conducting well.

Most semiconductor devices will be way less ideal than even the most rudimentary of mechanical switches. A mosfet is far from ideal in more ways than just having an "inaccurate" threshold voltage and a wide transition range from "blocking" to "conduction".

First of all, a mosfet *does* consume current. Both the gate and drain leakage are non-zero, and are orders of magnitude worse than with mechanical switches, especially when the device gets hot.

A mosfet also does not really open. A mosfet conducts way below the threshold voltage - its conduction is just sub-threshold, so the channel current will be low, but the device conducts nevertheless. E.g. you can use most CMOS digital logic in sub-threshold operation regime, like CD4000 logic at 1.5V, and so on.

So, the best you can do with a mosfet-based circuit is something micropower, but the power will not be zero. But the current draw can be comparable with self-discharge currents of most batteries, so its impact on longevity of a mobile power source will be nil or very close to.

The practical way of doing it is to use a nanopower comparator with a reference voltage source built-in, and use the output to switch a mosfet. One example of such a part is [TLV4062](https://www.ti.com/product/TLV4062) - it runs on 2uA. You won't be able to beat this current consumption with discrete parts, so that's your best bet.

If you really want to, you can go old-school and put together a solution that uses discrete CMOS transistors. It won't be great, but won't be too shabby either if you match devices that form differential pairs. You could be using monolithic pairs like those from CD4007 to improve matching, and improve the performance of the pass gate.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fC3OYq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

M1-M2 is a differential pair with a current mirror load M3-M4. M5 is an amplifier, and M6-M9 are the output inverters. M10-M13 is a bias current mirror. I1 can be a LM334 current reference set to 1uA. M20-M21 are a pass gate. The working voltage range of the pass gate switch is about 2V to VCC-2V.

The supply current is 4uA with switch open, 3uA with switch closed. The control voltage input is VCTL. The reference voltage is developed by passing 1uA reference current across R1-R2.

When implementing using a CD4007, the partitioning across the dies, as well as die utilization, is:

- U1: M10, M11, M12 (50%)
- U2: M1, M2, M13 (50%)
- U3: M3, M4, M5 (50%)
- U4: M6, M7, M8, M9, M20 (83%)
- U5: M20, M21, M21 (50%)

To improve the conductance of the switch, M20 and M21 could be discrete devices instead.

For unipolar loads, the series connection M20-M21 should be replaced with a single transistor, improving the conductance.

With CD4007 or with discrete transistors as shown, the supply range is 5-15V, with higher voltages recommended, as they widen the switch's operating range.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that it is possible to do that without consuming ANY current but there are a few ways of achieving what you are asking for with very low power consumption and also without the need to connect it to a supply voltage.

A so called bilateral switch can do what you are asking for and it usually does not consume a lot of power but it needs to be connected to a supply voltage and most are only designed for very low currents in the mA range. They are mostly used for analog mux applications.

You can also use a P-mos and connect a resistor from source to gate and a resistor from gate to the cathode of a shunt voltage reference such as the ZR431 and then controll the p-mos from the reference input of the ZR431. If the resistors i mentioned are made very large the current consumption from the source side of the switch/p-mos can be made very low and the ZR431 will provide a well defined switching point.

Comment: Do you desire NO power-supply? or NO steady-state power demand? How about 20 volt power supply, providing 1uA? and what about trigger accuracy, as temperature changes, or power supply voltage changes?

Comment: The mosfet+regulator seems like a good idea, so I guess it's just a matter of finding the lowest current regulator.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf no power-supply would be ideal (like a mosfet), but the important part is the low current, which should be in the singles of microamps

Answer (score 0):

There's a voltage-driven flexing device, a piezoelectric bimorph,
that takes very little (leakage) current, which could close an
electrical circuit.   Sensitivity is not usually very high, and
vibration might make the contact unreliable, so there isn't
a commercially available line of 'relays' based on it.[Piezo actuators](http://www.piezoproducts.com/en/piezo-piezoproducts/piezo-multilayer-bending-actuators/characteristics-of-piezo-multilayer-actuators/)   A combination of a bimorph actuator and a conventional
microswitch might suit the application.

Mostly, if any high current is to be conducted, one would want
to use a snap-action switch (with mechanical hysteresis), which
implies that contact closure voltage and contact release voltage
would be very different.   Without such snap-action, mechanical contacts
will get dirty (and either stick shut, or fail to fully close).